# Datadog Grok Parsing - extracting array attribute from nested JSON

Tags: parsing, datadog

Using Datadog Parsing rule, I am trying to extract an attribute which is present inside an array.

Sample I've been work on:

```
{"messageHeader":{"serviceId":"aad1","requestType":"MM"},"data":{"code":"400","reason":"Bad Request","message":[{"responseCode":"E111","description":"Unable to reserve request type"}]}}
```

what I wanted to achieve is:

```
{
    "description": "Unable to reserve request type",
    "responseCode": "E111"
}
```

I tried using this method - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62096791/8552537
but in log explorer I'm not getting the result.

Following the method explained in given link. First Grok parser:-

```
parsing_rule1 %{data::json}
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "reason": "Bad Request",
    "code": "400",
    "message": [
      {
        "description": "Unable to reserve request type",
        "responseCode": "E111"
      }
    ]
  },
  "messageHeader": {
    "requestType": "MM",
    "serviceId": "aad1"
  }
}
```

To create a custom log-based metrics, First we need to create a facet for responseCode but facet type doesn't support an array.

Now the goal is to pull out the details from that message field. With Grok parsers you can specify a specific attribute to parse further.

So in that same pipeline I've added another grok parser processor, right after our first.

And then configured the advanced options section to run on **data.message**, since that is what we called the attribute.
[helper grok parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQOba.png)

Result:
[helper grok parser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlDdR.png)

Comment: can you add the expression you've tried?

Comment: @bwest I've added the expressions.