# DataDog - Extracting headers from a JSON array in AWS WAFv2 JSON logs

Tags: arrays, json, flatten, datadog, amazon-waf

## Context

Parsing logs when using DataDog follows this principles:

- ideally, ingest already well-formated logs
- if not possible, pre-format the logs before sending them to DataDog collectors (can be done by 3rd party or a lambda function or the DataDog agent)
- if not, then use DataDog built-in parsing/post-formating capabilities (like Grok rules)

Technical context: infra-as-code, hosted on AWS. We use AWS's WAFv2 and centralize logs in a SIEM (DataDog in our case). AWS's WAFv2 are sent to DataDog using a Forwarder Lambda function, which is the recommended way.

The logs are sent  in the “native” and default format (JSON) without any modification. AWS WAF integration is installed. No custom log pipeline in place.

## Problem

The headers of the web requests handled by AWS's WAFv2 are included in the logs. They look like this:

```json
{
    [...SNIP...]
    "httpRequest": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "example.org"
            },
            {
                "name": "baz",
                "value": "qux"
            },
        ],
    [...SNIP...]
}
```

JSON paths:

- `Host` --> `httpRequest.headers[0].name`
- `example.org` --> `httpRequest.headers[0].value`

But they can also look like this:

```json
{
    [...SNIP...]
    "httpRequest": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "wx",
                "value": "yz"
            },
            {
                "name": "baz",
                "value": "qux"
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "example.org"
            },
        ],
    [...SNIP...]
}
```

JSON paths:

- `Host` --> `httpRequest.headers[2].name`
- `example.org` --> `httpRequest.headers[2].value`

*Note the change of numbers of headers and their order of appearance, and the indices we have to use to get the same header name and header value.*

Full examples of AWS WAFv2 logs are available on this page [Log Examples (docs.aws.amazon.com)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/logging-examples.html)

### Expected behavior

As a Security Analyst, I should be able to investigate the WAF's logs by filtering them based on any headers names and values. Example: filtering on `Host: example.org` should filter logs and display only the ones with this header.

### Actual behavior

I can only query logs that meet the following conditions:

- have a field named `httpRequest.headers.name` with the value `Host`
- AND have a field named `httpRequest.headers.value` with value `example.org`

But this is not the same as filtering on `Host: example.org`.

In fact, a request with those headers would also match because it has a header named `Host`and another one with value `example.org`.

```
Host: stackoverflow.com
X-Remote: example.org
```

## Attempts

### Relying on indices (fail)

I tried this log search query:

```
httpRequest.headers.name[0]:Host AND httpRequest.headers.value[0]:example.org
```

This could work if all the logs had the same number of headers appearing in the same order in the array. Turns out it's not, because those come from a client request on the Internet.

### Using the String builder processor

This is the attempt of DataDog support at fixing my problem:

1. Create a String Builder Processor
   using the following value:

```
%{httpRequest.headers.name} %{httpRequest.headers.value}
```

to extract the desired attributes from the log and set them to a new attribute `extracted.data`.

2. Create a Grok parser
   Rule

```
rule1 %{data} (%{data:extracted.host} %{data} %{data} %{data} %{data} %{data} %{data} %{data} %{data})
```

While specifying to extract from `extracted.data` in the Advanced settings.

While this is an interesting approach, it does not cover the use case and does not work:

- it does not allow me filter any header, I have to write a rule per header I want to extract (which is not ideal security investigations)
- this actually fails to correctly extract the value. As you can see in your screenshot:
  [screenshot_of_parsing_attempt_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8q4l.png). The host field is polluted with a fragment of the `User-Agent` header value.

## Ideal solution

We also thought on dumping the logs somewhere, then processing them to format them in an easier to parse format, before sending them to our SIEM. But the amount of logs would cost too much (compute, storage, etc.). A native solution (in AWS ou in DataDog) would be much more cost-efficient.

Long story short, the ideal solution would enable a DataDog user to change this:

```json
[...SNIP...]
"headers": 
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
    },
    {
        "name": "baz",
        "value": "qux"
    },
[...SNIP...]
```

To:

```json
[...SNIP...]
"headers": 
    {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": "qux"
    },
[...SNIP...]
```

What is the appropriate term to do that? Flattening? Reassociating?

Has anyone already managed to do this?

## Research & resources

We reached DataDog support, but the solution they proposed was not working (see above).

During my own research, I found:

- [this question on StackOverflow: Datadog Grok Parsing - extracting fields from nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092243/datadog-grok-parsing-extracting-fields-from-nested-json).

--> An interesting solution for a quite similar problem. I can't figure out how to apply it to my use-case though.

- [this question on StackOverflow: Datadog Grok Parsing - extracting array attribute from nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168220/datadog-grok-parsing-extracting-array-attribute-from-nested-json).
  --> No answer.
- [this discussion on Elastic.co forum: Split filter question a.k.a flatten JSON sub array](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-split-filter-question-a-k-a-flatten-json-sub-array/130481)

--> Similar issue, interesting grok-based solution for ElasticSearch. Not applicable to DataDog as it's not possible to implement complex Grok rules.

## Sources & references

- <sub>1</sub> [Parsing](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/?tab=matchers)
- <sub>2</sub> [Log Parsing — Best Practices](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/log-parsing-best-practice/)